# Phonegap - How do perform view click or document click programmatically?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, cordova-plugins

is there any way to do page(document) click/touch action programmatically in Phonegap ap similar to native `button.performClick()`?

I know `document.addEventListener("resume", yourCallbackFunction, false);` will help in knowing application `resume` state. What I need is perform programmatic click in `resume` callback to dismiss some animated splash screen running in native layers.

Comment: splashscreens on native layer. You mean those screens are not displayed on Webview?

Comment: Actually I am attaching splash screen from my custom plugin to the webview. It is a custom view rendered from native layer.